# DI with arguments in the constructor

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice

So I'm implementing a Dependency Injection framework into my Java project (Google Guice) and everything is pretty good, I like it but there's a small problem;
I want to make a **static** instance of my main project's class (where it instantiates the dependencies, etc). But I don't know any method to instantiate it using Guice, I can't instantiate it manually because I'm using DI in the constructor of it (I have objects in the constructor) which means that I am not able to access the class' non-static variables needed to instantiate the class.
I tried using a Provider but I couldn't really understand where to bind it, because I don't want to have an interface for the main class (will if needed).

Comment: Static and DI are anathema. Why do you think you need a static instance?

Comment: I need a static instance because I use the class' methods in other classes. And I don't want to instantiate it again every time I would want to use it (a lot)

Comment: So... inject the instance? Make it [@Singleton](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/Scopes)?

Comment: What do you mean by injecting the instance? I'm really new to DI, I tried searching for this in different places but I could not find the correct "word" to search for :/

Comment: How are you using guice without knowing what injection is?

Comment: I do know what it is, I was just asking a question :/

Answer (score 3):

If you are wanting to mix a static instance of a class with dependency injection, you have somewhat missed the point of dependency injection: you can simply inject the instance of the class.

If you want there to be a single instance of a class for your injector, bind it in `@Singleton` scope: either:

```
bind(YourClass.class).in(Singleton.class);
```

in your module's `configure()` method, or

```
@Provides @Singleton YourClass provideYourClassInstance() {
  // ...
}
```

in your module, or

```
@Singleton class YourClass {
  // ...
}
```

in the actual class declaration.

Then just inject this instance like any other:

```
class SomeOtherClass {
  @Inject SomeOtherClass(YourClass instance) {
    // ... Do something with instance, like assign it to a field.
  }
}
```

The point is that `SomeOtherClass` shouldn't need know anything about the lifetime of `instance`: it simply doesn't matter whether this is a singleton instance, or every class using it has its own instance.

Comment: Oh yes, what I wanted was to have a static instance for the main class because I have getters in it that I access multiple times, from multiple classes.

Answer (score 2):

You can get three different answers here depending on the question.

To directly answer the question in the title (DI with arguments in the constructor), you can mix DI with constuctor arguments by instead injecting a Factory. Though you're welcome to write one manually, Guice can do this for you as [assisted injection](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/AssistedInject) (see [FactoryModuleBuilder](https://google.github.io/guice/api-docs/latest/javadoc/com/google/inject/assistedinject/FactoryModuleBuilder.html)), or you can use the equivalent code-generated solution [AutoFactory](https://github.com/google/auto/tree/master/factory) popular through Dagger.

If you're trying to initialize a static class's fields in a Guice application, Guice can do that for you as soon as the Injector is created. Simply call [requestStaticInjection](https://google.github.io/guice/api-docs/4.1/javadoc/com/google/inject/Binder.html#requestStaticInjection-java.lang.Class...-) in a Module you feed to Guice. This, as Andy Turner pointed out, will cause you to miss out on some of the benefits of Guice: Because you're injecting the instance statically, there's very little opportunity for you to provide replacement implementations in tests or in other class reuse. Guice describes this more in the [static injections section](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/Injections#static-injections) of its wiki:

> When migrating an application from static factories to Guice, it is possible to change incrementally. Static injection is a helpful crutch here. It makes it possible for objects to partially participate in dependency injection, by gaining access to injected types without being injected themselves. [...]
>
> Static members will not be injected at instance-injection time. This API is not recommended for general use because it suffers many of the same problems as static factories: it's clumsy to test, it makes dependencies opaque, and it relies on global state.

The best overall solution is in [Andy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43148380/1426891): Adapt your application to use DI, which will let it inject the objects that you would otherwise make static.